# Storing image as a String in Sqlite in Flutter and Decoding it

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to store the image as a base64 string in Sqlite in Flutter, and then decode that base64 into image and display it. Here is my utility code that has functions of encoding and decoding base64:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';



class Utility {
  static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64String),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }

  static Uint8List dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return base64Decode(base64String);
  }

  static String base64String(Uint8List data) {
    return base64Encode(data);
  }
}
```

Now I have this function that should pick the image with Image Picker from gallery, and then encode it to base64, but I am getting an error:

```
 _getImage() {
picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((imgFile) {
  String imgString = Utility.base64String(imgFile.readAsBytes());
});
```

}

The error:

```
The argument type 'Future<Uint8List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
```

After that would be stored in Sqlite (this is obviously not full code), I would then just decode it in a list tile or whatever like this:

```
Utility.imageFromBase64String(employee.photo);
```

What am I doing wrong, and also, if you guys know a good and clean way to store the base64 string and then decode it in Sqlite in Flutter, let me know. Thank you!

**EDIT**

When I add `readAsBytesSync` I'm getting this error instead, not sure what the issue is:

```
The method 'readAsBytesSync' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytesSync'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [File class documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html). You can see that `readAsBytes` function returns `Future<Uint8List>`, that's why you are getting that error. To fix this issue, you have to use `readAsBytesSync` which returns `Uint8List`.

Replace:

```
String imgString = Utility.base64String(imgFile.readAsBytes());
```

with:

```
String imgString = Utility.base64String(imgFile.readAsBytesSync());
```

#### Update:

The image picker uses a class called [PickedFile](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker_platform_interface/lib/src/types/picked_file/io.dart) to provide the file details bac, which doesn't support `readAsBytesSync`. So you can use:

```
final file = File(imgFile.path);
String imgString = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
```

Comment: Or learn that any time you see a Future<something> value, you forgot an await somewhere. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz You are correct :) An advice every flutter dev should always remember

Comment: It's appreciated, but I already tried readAsBytesSync, but then I get this error:

Comment: `The method 'readAsBytesSync' isn't defined for the type 'PickedFile'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytesSync'.`

Comment: @arbiter Yeah, which uses a custom class for handling file, which doesn't support the mentioned method. I've updated my answer. Please check