# Storing local image in database and displaying test

Tags: flutter, image, sqlite, dart, assets

I'am testing a little flutter app that should be able to store a local asset image into a database and then show it in a gridview. As you can se below I have db_helper methods that create the db and saves and get the photos.

I have also utillity methods that should convert the image String to base64 for storing in db and also for showing pic on screen. The Photo class itself have one toMap and one fromMap method to use with db methods. This works fine when I use the imagePicker method (pickImagesFromGallery) below but when I try my own method (pickImagesFromAssets) to put image from asset into database I get below error message. The error message is displayed when I click on the + button to add my local image.

I have tried to use Future builder as well to get it working but its probably an error in my code or my logic. I have here what I think is the most relevant code. Please can you guys give me input how to solve this and maybe the best way to be able to also save local images to the database?

db_helper class:

```
Future<Photo> save(Photo photo) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    photo.id = await dbClient.insert(TABLE, photo.toMap());
    return photo;
  }

  //Get all photos from db
  Future<List<Photo>> getPhotos() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [ID, fName]);
    List<Photo> photos = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        photos.add(Photo.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return photos;
  }
```

Utility class:

```
class Utility {
  static Image imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64String),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }

  static Uint8List dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return base64Decode(base64String);
  }

  //Takes a String path and makes a base64 String object?
  static String base64String(Uint8List data) {
    return base64Encode(data);
  }
}
```

Photo class:

```
class Photo {
  int? id;
  String? fileName;
  String? displayName;

  Photo({this.id, this.fileName});

  //Todo we have to make a Photo of the asset photos
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = {
      'id': id,
      'fileName': fileName,
      //'dispayName': displayName,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Photo.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    id = map['id'];
    fileName = map['fileName'];
    //displayName = map['displayName'];
  }
}
```

image_screen class:

```
class _ImageScreenState extends State<ImageScreen> {
  Future<File>? imageFile;
  Image? image;
  DBHelper? dbHelper;
  List<Photo>? images;
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? im = XFile('images/flower1.png');

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    images = [];
    dbHelper = DBHelper();
    refreshImages();
  }

  refreshImages() {
    
    dbHelper!.getPhotos().then((imgs) {
      setState(() {
        //Clears list
        images!.clear();
        //Add all images from imgs (database) to images list
        images!.addAll(imgs);
      });
    });
  }

  pickImagesFromAssets() {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373667/storing-image-as-a-string-in-sqlite-in-flutter-and-decoding-it
    //The image picker uses a class called PickedFile to provide the file details bac, which doesn't support readAsBytesSync
    //so

    final file = File(im!.path);
    String imgString = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
    Photo photo = Photo(id: 0, fileName: imgString);
    dbHelper!.save(photo);
    refreshImages();
  }

  Future<bool> imagesNotNull() async {
    var images = await pickImagesFromAssets();
    return images;
  }

  pickImagesFromGallery() {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373667/storing-image-as-a-string-in-sqlite-in-flutter-and-decoding-it
    //The image picker uses a class called PickedFile to provide the file details bac, which doesn't support readAsBytesSync
    //so
    imagePicker
        //Testing setting image quality to 50 and see what happens
        //Its working with image quality 50%
        // I think the file is put in imgFile by the .then keyword?
        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50)
        .then((imgFile) {
      final file = File(imgFile!.path);
      String imgString = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
      Photo photo = Photo(id: 0, fileName: imgString);
      dbHelper!.save(photo);
      refreshImages();
    });
  }

  //Todo Database brakes after adding a couple highres images. lowresulotion images from whatsapp is working better
  //Todo Need to be able to compress image size. I think BLOB should work better for database

  gridview() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: images!.map((photo) {
          return Utility.imageFromBase64String(photo.fileName!);
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Center(child: Text('ImagePicker Database test')),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                pickImagesFromAssets();
                //pickImagesFromGallery();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
                future: imagesNotNull(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[Flexible(child: gridview())],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                        child: Text('No data yet, click "+" to add some'));
                  }
                })
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Error message:

[image]

[image]

Edit:

I have now added a getImageFileFromAssets like below but unfortunatly I get another error when I click the + button (below). I suppose the error is somewhere in the conversion but I cannot figure out where?:

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }

  Future<Photo>? pickImagesFromAssets() async {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373667/storing-image-as-a-string-in-sqlite-in-flutter-and-decoding-it
    //The image picker uses a class called PickedFile to provide the file details bac, which doesn't support readAsBytesSync
    //so
    String pic = "images/flower1.png";
    //var assetImage = AssetImage(pic);
    var file = await getImageFileFromAssets(pic);
    String imgString = Utility.base64String(file.readAsBytesSync());
    Photo photo = Photo(id: 0, fileName: imgString);
    dbHelper!.save(photo);
    refreshImages();
    return photo;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't just load a file from your local file system in flutter, the file system in android/ios/whatever is not your project directory, you have to bundle it with your app as an asset and read it through `rootBundle` for example. See: [Adding assets and images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: Another maybe more simple question for you more experienced guys/girls out there. If I have both asset image files and picked images (from users) that I want to show in the app which way is the best to go? With this I mean should I try to implement it so that everything can fit into a database and then pick images to show from there or is it a better way doing it? There seems to be problems when I convert asset-files to base64 db-format and then back again to display them, I get something like "window size is to big"

Answer (score 0):

Error message says `No such file or directory`.

Please make sure the file exists. Then, rebuild your project (Hot Reload won't give you access to the image until you rebuild the app) and it may work.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and the file exists as you can see in the last picture.

Comment: Ok, did you add the path "images/" to your pubspec.yaml ?

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images